# React JS React-router-dom Navigate not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I try to redirect the user after login in my React App, but Navigate won't work and i don't know why...

Here is my code and thanks for your help

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Bouton from "../components/Bouton";

class Dallan extends Component{
    logout = () =>{
        localStorage.removeItem('logged');
        return <Navigate to= '/login' />;
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Bouton typeBtn = 'btn-danger' click={() => this.logout()}>Deconnexion</Bouton>
        )
    }
}

export default Dallan;
```

And in my App.js

```
function App() {
  let session = localStorage.getItem('logged');
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={session ? <Navigate to="/dallan" /> : <Login/>} />
       <Route path='/dallan' element={<Dallan/>}/>
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
 
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try using Redirect instead of Navigate

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using react route dom v6 which I assume you are by the use of `<Navigate />` then `<Navigate />` is a component which would need to be rendered to work. You are just returning it to nothing so it obviously won't render. You want to use the `useNavigate()` hook instead. But you will want to use a function component to use the hook. Like so:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Route, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Bouton from "../components/Bouton";

function Dallan() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const  logout = () =>{
        localStorage.removeItem('logged');
        navigate('/login')
    }

    return(
        <Bouton typeBtn = 'btn-danger' click={() => logout()}>Deconnexion</Bouton>
    )
}

export default Dallan;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use navigate method in useEffect like this:

Imports

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
```

Use following code

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [logged, setLogged] = useState(null);

const logout = () => {
   localStorage.clear();
   console.log("Logged out");
   setLogged(Math.random());
};

useEffect(() => {
  navigate("/login");
}, [logged]);
```

Answer (score -1):

technically it should work try writing it like so, `return <Navigate replace={true} to='/' />` enssure that you place the replace={true} because its job is to redirect meaning it replaces everything on the page with where you are redirecting to user to

Comment: No. It can not work. The accepted answer explains why it can't work. Adding `replace={true}` wont fix it.